# Круговой прогресс бар

Tags: html5, css3, svg, css-animation

Как я могу создать этот круговой прогресс-бар с помощью `CSS`. Это вообще возможно добиться совместимости браузеров - ie10+, ФФ, хром, сафари?
Я думаю мы можем для этого использовать `SVG`, но я не знаю как это сделать.

По кругу, есть небольшие границы или тени, которые динамически меняются в зависимости от процентного прогресса. Если этот процент составляет 100%, граница будет полностью по кругу заполнять прогресс-бар.

[image: круговой прелоадер]

Источник: [Circle border progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41586078/circle-border-progress-bar/41586345#41586345)

Comment: Предыдущая статья от того же автора http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628297/%d0%9a%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%80

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41586078/circle-border-progress-bar/41586345#41586345

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Этот круговой прогресс-бар  является дополнением к моему же предыдущему ответу : [круговой прогресс-бар](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29512804/1811992)
В этом ответе использован `SVG` совместно с `JS` библиотекой `Snap.svg` для анимации круговой синей строки и счетчика процентов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var count = $(('#count'));
$({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: count.text() }, {
  duration: 5000,
  easing: 'linear',
  step: function () {
    count.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter)+ "%");
  }
});

var s = Snap('#animated');
var progress = s.select('#progress');

progress.attr({strokeDasharray: '0, 251.2'});
Snap.animate(0,251.2, function( value ) {
    progress.attr({ 'stroke-dasharray':value+',251.2'});
}, 5000);
```

```css
body{text-align:center;font-family:sans-serif;background:#080808;}
svg{width:30%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.3.0/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="animated" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <path id="progress" stroke-width="3" stroke="#4596AB" fill="none"
        d="M50 10
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80">
  </path>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="38" fill="transparent" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1"/>
  <text id="count" x="50" y="50" fill="#fff" text-anchor="middle" dy="7" font-size="20">100%</text>
</svg>
```

Ответил: [web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki)