# Круговой процентный прогресс бар

Tags: html, css, css3, анимация, svg

Мне хотелось бы иметь круговой процентный показатель  на моем сайте:

[image: круговой процентный показатель]

В этом случае, см. рисунок, он показывает 75%. Как это может быть сделано?
У меня есть желтый круг в `image-file`, но может быть проще, как  делают это некоторые,  все с помощью CSS?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Circular percent progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29350504/7394871) от участника  [@dhrm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/617413/dhrm).</sub>

Comment: А вы ассоциацию в табличку на Мете добавляете?

Comment: из этой таблички Николас берет пары и добавляет в базу.

Comment: Другими словами, комментарий про ассоциацию *обычно* обозначает, что вопрос был добавлен в табличку, и его не нужно добавлять ещё раз. Если вы ставите комментарий, а в табличку не добавляете — ещё меньше шанс, что кто-то другой добавит.

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29350504/circular-percent-progress-bar/29512804#29512804

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Учитывая форму прогресс-бара (закругленный конец/начало), я хотел бы предложить, использование SVG.

**DEMO**: [Radial progress bar](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/qEGvMN)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В следующем примере, прогресс идет в сочетании с атрибутом `stroke-dasharray` , а процент числа увеличиваются с `jQuery`:

```js
var count = $(('#count'));
$({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: count.text() }, {
  duration: 5000,
  easing: 'linear',
  step: function () {
    count.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter)+ "%");
  }
});
```

```css
body{text-align:center;font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;}
svg{width:25%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="animated" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="#FDB900"/>
  <path fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="5" stroke="#fff"
        stroke-dasharray="251.2,0"
        d="M50 10
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80">
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" from="0,251.2" to="251.2,0" dur="5s"/>           
  </path>
  <text id="count" x="50" y="50" text-anchor="middle" dy="7" font-size="20">100%</text>
</svg>
```

К сожалению, браузер`IE` не поддерживает SVG-анимации `SMIL`. Для достижения такого же результата с поддержкой `IE`, вы можете использовать библиотеки, такие как `Snap.SVG` и анимировать атрибут `stroke-dasharray`  с `JS` :

```js
var count = $(('#count'));
$({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: count.text() }, {
  duration: 5000,
  easing: 'linear',
  step: function () {
    count.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter)+ "%");
  }
});

var s = Snap('#animated');
var progress = s.select('#progress');

progress.attr({strokeDasharray: '0, 251.2'});
Snap.animate(0,251.2, function( value ) {
    progress.attr({ 'stroke-dasharray':value+',251.2'});
}, 5000);
```

```css
body{text-align:center;font-family:sans-serif;}
svg{width:25%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.3.0/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<svg id="svg" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="#FDB900"/>
  <path fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="5" stroke="#fff"
        stroke-dasharray="1,250.2"
        d="M50 10
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80"/>
  <text x="50" y="50" text-anchor="middle" dy="7" font-size="20">1%</text>
</svg>
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="#FDB900"/>
  <path fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="5" stroke="#fff"
        stroke-dasharray="125.6,125.6"
        d="M50 10
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80"/>
  <text x="50" y="50" text-anchor="middle" dy="7" font-size="20">50%</text>
</svg>

<svg id="animated" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="#FDB900"/>
  <path id="progress" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="5" stroke="#fff" fill="none"
        d="M50 10
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80">
  </path>
  <text id="count" x="50" y="50" text-anchor="middle" dy="7" font-size="20">100%</text>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29512804/7394871) от участника  [@web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki).</sub>

Comment: У меня второй вариант не сработал :(

Comment: @Yuri попробуй сейчас.... подправил

Comment: Теперь отлично :)

Comment: Продолжение от того же автора http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628257/%d0%9a%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%80

Comment: Вопрос: в примере есть аттрибут `stroke-dasharray="125.6,125.6"`  и `stroke-dasharray="0,250.2"` - Как определяется 2-е число?

Comment: @Дмытрык  `250.2` - общая длина окружности  `stroke-dasharray="125.6,125.6` данная запись обозначает - черта 125.6 пробел 125.6 Может вам будет полезен мой топик [Помогите с dasharray и dashoffset](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/761733/28748) Всё очень подробно и надеюсь доступно

Comment: Спасибо, почитал. Но, пока не понял, как вышло, что в Вашем примере длина окружности равна 250 или 125. У меня получается 282: `r="45" * 2 * пи` ... Я вынесу это в отдельный вопрос. Минут через 20

Comment: разместил вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1023436/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b0-stroke-dasharray

Comment: @Дмытрык если вопрос ещё актуален, посмотрите [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1025723/28748). Не мог ответить раньше, - отсутствовал на сайте с 11 сентября