# Как сделать SVG circle более четким?

Tags: html, svg

Всем привет!

Видно на картинке, что круг немного пиксельный, можно ли смазать пиксели или есть другой способ сделать этот круг более четким?
[image]

P.S.
Зеленая полоска анимированная, в зависимости от цифры, полоска доходит до определенного момента.

Сам код:

```css
svg {
  width: 85px;
  height: 85px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 85 85">
  <circle r="40" stroke-width="3" stroke="#6d6d6d" fill="transparent" cy="42.5" cx="42.5"></circle>
  <circle r="40" stroke-width="2" stroke="#00c81c" fill="transparent" cy="42.5" cx="42.5"></circle>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нарисовать обводку поверх фигуры:

```css
svg {
  width: 85px;
  height: 85px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 85 85"  shape-rendering="geometricPrecision">
  <circle r="40" stroke-width="2" stroke="#6d6d6d" fill="none" cy="42" cx="42"></circle>
  <circle r="40" stroke-width="2" stroke="#00c81c" fill="none" cy="42" cx="42"></circle>
  <circle r="41" stroke-width="0.5" stroke="#6d6d6d" fill="none" cy="42" cx="42"></circle>
  <circle r="39" stroke-width="0.5" stroke="#6d6d6d" fill="none" cy="42" cx="42"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Не понимаю зачем лишний код, ведь это векторный формат, который не нуждается в костылях при обработке границ и задавать жестко размеры блока svg в css правилах, значит лишать его главного преимущества - масштабирование без потери качества

Comment: @Alexandr_T Одно дело отрисовать нормальную обводку, другое иммитировать ее наложением элементов друг на друга.

Comment: так я в ответе ниже пояснил причину появления размытости :)

Comment: @Alexandr_T  посмотрите вопрос, _можно ли смазать пиксели_? Автор вопроса ругается на аляйсинг, а не на размытость

Comment: В моем примере есть аляйсинг?

Answer (score 2):

- Замените fill="transparent" на fill="none"
- svg - блок обернуть контейнером  и задавать размеры для div, а не для svg
- координаты круга сделать целочисленными cy="43"  cx ="43"

```css
.container
{
width: 88;
height: 88;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg width="88" height="88" viewBox="0 0 88 88">
  <circle r="40" stroke-width="2" stroke="#6d6d6d" fill="none" cy="43" cx="43"></circle>
  <circle r="40" stroke-width="2" stroke="#00c81c" fill="none" cy="43" cx="43"></circle>
</svg>  
</div>
```

Может быть оказывает влияние, что у вас один круг накладывается на другой, но у этих кругов вы задали разную ширину обводки.
 Дело в том, что `stroke` располагается симметрично по обоим сторонам. То есть, если у вас радиус равен 40px при  stroke-width ="2px" цветной бордюр будет между радиусами 39px и 41px. При stroke-width ="3px" соответственно 38.5px и 41.5px.
 У вас больший круг расположен ниже, меньшего круга, поэтому при разных цветах бордюров возможно размытие границ.

Другими словами или сделайте одинаковую ширину `stroke-width` или пусть   круг, где stroke-width="3px" будет сверху.

Comment: Никаких изменений https://jsfiddle.net/faa9q947/

Comment: @Александр Рейдзан попробуйте еще раз, к теоритическим рассуждениям добавлен код

Comment: @Александр Рейдзан вам в помощь,  здесь на сайте, есть что-то подобное - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/628312/28748