# Бордер в процентах

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, svg

Пытаюсь понять, как сделать такой бордер

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть очевидный вариант с отрисовкой 100 картинок под каждый процент, но хотелось бы что нибудь на css и js.
Примеров кода нет, т.к даже микроидей нет.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Проще, лучше и красивее - будет реализовать такое на SVG, например:

```js
var count = $(('#count'));
$({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: count.text() }, {
  duration: 5000,
  easing: 'linear',
  step: function () {
    count.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter)+ "%");
  }
});

var s = Snap('#animated');
var progress = s.select('#progress');

progress.attr({strokeDasharray: '0, 251.2'});
Snap.animate(0,251.2, function( value ) {
    progress.attr({ 'stroke-dasharray':value+',251.2'});
}, 5000);
```

```css
body{text-align:center;font-family:sans-serif;}
svg{width:30%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.3.0/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<svg id="svg" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="#FDB900"/>
  <path fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="5" stroke="#fff"
        stroke-dasharray="1,250.2"
        d="M50 10
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80"/>
  <text x="50" y="50" text-anchor="middle" dy="7" font-size="20">1%</text>
</svg>
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="#FDB900"/>
  <path fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="5" stroke="#fff"
        stroke-dasharray="125.6,125.6"
        d="M50 10
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80"/>
  <text x="50" y="50" text-anchor="middle" dy="7" font-size="20">50%</text>
</svg>

<svg id="animated" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="#FDB900"/>
  <path id="progress" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="5" stroke="#fff" fill="none"
        d="M50 10
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80">
  </path>
  <text id="count" x="50" y="50" text-anchor="middle" dy="7" font-size="20">100%</text>
</svg>
```

Источник: [Круговой процентный прогресс бар | StackOverflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/628312/221218)

---

Можно конечно и на JS\JQ, но будет это несколько кривовато и больше кода займёт.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!)

Comment: @Dimabytes, не за что)