# stroke-dasharray через style

Tags: jquery, svg, анимация, svg-animation

Есть следующий код:

```js
$('input[type="button"]').on('click', function(){
  StartFill();
});

function StartFill() {
 let timer = 1000*5;
  $('.status').css('background', 'green');
 $('#fill path')
   .css('stroke-dasharray', '0, 251.2')
    .animate({
   'stroke-dasharray': '251.2, 251.2'
  }, timer, 'linear', function(){
    $('#fill path').css('stroke-dasharray', '0, 251.2');
    $('.status').css('background', 'red');
  });
}
```

```css
#fill {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.status {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- -->
<svg id="fill" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <path fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="5" stroke="#07f" d="M50 10 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80">
  </path>
</svg>
<div class="status"></div>
<br>
<input type="button" value="start">
```

По задумке, при нажатии на кнопку `"start"` бордюр круга должен заполниться (как [круговой прогресс бар](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/628312/221218)).
Но он не хочет..

Думаю проблема в том, что `.animate()` не так "воспроизводит" "механику" `stroke-dasharray`.

Как можно "переиграть" данное действие?

---

P.s.

`<animate>` предлагать только в том случае, если можно "узнать" когда конец анимации.
`<div class="status">` просто для визуального отображения того, что действие `.animate()` работает.

Comment: Используй css-анимацию.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 плюсанул за хороший вопрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

можно пошагово обновлять атрибут

```js
$('input[type="button"]').on('click', function(){
  StartFill();
});

function StartFill() {
  $('.status').css('background', 'green');

  const animationOptions = {
    duration: 1000*5,
    step: function(now) {
      $(this).attr("stroke-dasharray", `${now}, 251.2`);
    },
    easing: 'linear',
    complete: function() {
      $('#fill path').attr('stroke-dasharray', '0, 251.2');
      $('.status').css('background', 'red');
    },
  };

  $('#fill path')
    .css('percent-load', 0)
    .animate({ 'percent-load': 251.2 }, animationOptions);
}
```

```css
#fill {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.status {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="fill" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <path fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="5" stroke="#07f" d="M50 10 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80">
  </path>
</svg>
<div class="status"></div>
<br>
<input type="button" value="start">
```

Comment: Опа, про `step`-то я и забыл, спасибо за ответ)

Answer (score 3):

### Все варианты анимации `animate` исключительно `stroke-dasharray`

Чтобы лучше понять, как это работает, [можно почитать топик на нашем сайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/760290/28748).

**1. Один сегмент**

Левая кнопка **"L"** заполнение окружности

Правая **"R"** - уменьшение заполнения

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 100 100">

<path fill="none"  stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="5" stroke="#e1e1e1" d="M50 10 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80"/> 

<path fill="none" stroke-dasharray="0 251" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="5" stroke="#07f"
     d="M50 10 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80">  
    <animate
   attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   values="0 251; 251 0"
   begin="btn_L.click"
   dur="4s"
   restart="whenNotActive"
   fill="freeze" />  
 <animate
   attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   values="251 0; 0 251"
   begin="btn_R.click"
   dur="4s"
   restart="whenNotActive"
   fill="freeze" />  
  
</path> 

<g id="btn_L" transform="translate(-17 0)" >
      <rect x="20" y="84" width="15" height="15" rx="7.5" fill="none" stroke="#B2B2B2"/>
      <text x="25" y="95" font-size="10" fill="green" >L</text>
</g>  
 
    <g id="btn_R" transform="translate(60 0)" >
      <rect x="20" y="84" width="15" height="15" rx="7.5" fill="none" stroke="#B2B2B2"/>
      <text x="25" y="95" font-size="10" fill="crimson" >R</text>
    </g>
```

**2. Синхронно из одной общей точки**

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 100 100">

<path fill="none"  stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="5" stroke="#e1e1e1" d="M50 10 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80"/> 

<path fill="none" stroke-dasharray="0 125.6 0 125.6" stroke-dashoffset="125.6" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="5" stroke="#07f" d="M50 10 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80">  
 <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" values="0 125.6 0 125.6; 0 0 251 0" begin="btn_L.click" dur="4s"  restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" />  
 <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" values="0 0 251 0;0 125.6 0 125.6" begin="btn_R.click" dur="4s"  restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" />  
 
 
 </path> 
  </path>

<g id="btn_L" transform="translate(-17 0)" >
      <rect x="20" y="84" width="15" height="15" rx="7.5" fill="none" stroke="#B2B2B2"/>
      <text x="25" y="95" font-size="10" fill="green" >L</text>
    </g>  
 
<g id="btn_R" transform="translate(60 0)" >
      <rect x="20" y="84" width="15" height="15" rx="7.5" fill="none" stroke="#B2B2B2"/>
      <text x="25" y="95" font-size="10" fill="crimson" >R</text>
    </g>
```

**3. Два сегмента**

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 100 100">

<path fill="none"  stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="5" stroke="#e1e1e1" d="M50 10 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80"/> 

<path fill="none" stroke-dasharray="0 251" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="5" stroke="#07f"
     d="M50 10 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80">  
    <animate
   attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   values="0 125.6 0 125.6;125.6 0 125.6 0"
   begin="btn_L.click"
   dur="4s"
   restart="whenNotActive"
   fill="freeze" />  
 <animate
   attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   values="125.6 0 125.6 0;0 125.6 0 125.6"
   begin="btn_R.click"
   dur="4s"
   restart="whenNotActive"
   fill="freeze" />  
  
</path> 

<g id="btn_L" transform="translate(-17 0)" >
      <rect x="20" y="84" width="15" height="15" rx="7.5" fill="none" stroke="#B2B2B2"/>
      <text x="25" y="95" font-size="10" fill="green" >L</text>
</g>  
 
    <g id="btn_R" transform="translate(60 0)" >
      <rect x="20" y="84" width="15" height="15" rx="7.5" fill="none" stroke="#B2B2B2"/>
      <text x="25" y="95" font-size="10" fill="crimson" >R</text>
    </g>
```

**4. Три сегмента**

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 100 100">

<path fill="none"  stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="5" stroke="#e1e1e1" d="M50 10 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80"/> 

<path fill="none" stroke-dasharray="0 83.66 0 83.66 0 83.66" stroke-dashoffset="125.6" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="5" stroke="#07f" d="M50 10 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80">  
 <animate
   attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   values="0 83.66 0 83.66 0 83.66;
   83.66 0 83.66 0 83.66 0"
   begin="btn_L.click"
   dur="4s"
   restart="whenNotActive"
   fill="freeze" />  
 <animate
   attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   values="83.66 0 83.66 0 83.66 0;
   0 83.66 0 83.66 0 83.66"
   begin="btn_R.click"
   dur="4s"
   restart="whenNotActive"
   fill="freeze" />  
  
</path> 
  

<g id="btn_L" transform="translate(-17 0)" >
      <rect x="20" y="84" width="15" height="15" rx="7.5" fill="none" stroke="#B2B2B2"/>
      <text x="25" y="95" font-size="10" fill="green" >L</text>
    </g>  
 
<g id="btn_R" transform="translate(60 0)" >
      <rect x="20" y="84" width="15" height="15" rx="7.5" fill="none" stroke="#B2B2B2"/>
      <text x="25" y="95" font-size="10" fill="crimson" >R</text>
    </g>
```