# Определение длины окружности для аттрибута stroke-dasharray

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, snapsvg

[Круговой процентный прогресс бар](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628297/%d0%9a%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%80/628312#628312)
В данном ответе на вопрос, есть такой код:

```
<svg id="svg" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="#FDB900"/>
  <path fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="5" stroke="#fff"
        stroke-dasharray="1,250.2"
        d="M50 10
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80"/>
  <text x="50" y="50" text-anchor="middle" dy="7" font-size="20">1%</text>
</svg>

<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="#FDB900"/>
  <path fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="5" stroke="#fff"
        stroke-dasharray="125.6,125.6"
        d="M50 10
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80"/>
  <text x="50" y="50" text-anchor="middle" dy="7" font-size="20">50%</text>
</svg>
```

Как видно, тут 2 одинаковых svg элемента, в которых есть `path` c атрибутом `stroke-dasharray`. В первом случае, атрибут имеет значение `1,250.2`, во втором, `125.6,125.6`.  Второе значение в данном атрибуте - это длина окружности.
По моим подсчетам, длина окружности должна быть 282.74... (`r="45" * 2 * пи`), однако, в коде, она совсем другая.

Вопрос: Почему длина окружности у двух одинаковых svg - разная?
Что влияет на ее значение?
Как ее правильно посчитать?

Comment: `stroke-dasharray` никак не связан с окружностью, второе число там это размер пропуска между штрихами, у круга радиус 45, но у дуг окружностей радиус 40, `40*2*3.14=251.2`

Comment: ну Вы правильно считаете, только радиус не тот взяли

Comment: @StrangerintheQ радиус 40 получился `r - stroke-width`?

Comment: нет, `a 40 40` это команда дуги эллипса с радиусами 40 и 40, то есть окружности с радиусом 40

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, благодарю)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему длина окружности у двух одинаковых svg - разная? Что влияет на
>   ее значение? Как ее правильно посчитать?

Как ответил в комментарии @StrangerintheQ  радиус окружности в данном примере равен `40` при этом значении радиуса полная длина окружности равна - `40*2*3.14=251.2`

- Первый фрагмент кода показывает сегмент окружности равной одному
  проценту от общей длины.

  `stroke-dasharray="1,250.2"`, где длина черты -`1` пробел равен `250.2` в сумме это будет вся длина окружности -`251.2`

```html
<svg id="svg" width="25%" height="25%" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="#FDB900"/>
  <path fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="5" stroke="#fff"
        stroke-dasharray="1,250.2"
        d="M50 10
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80"/>
  <text x="50" y="50" text-anchor="middle" dy="7" font-size="20">1%</text>
</svg>
```

- Второй фрагмент кода показывает сегмент окружности равной половине
  от общей длины, то есть `50%`

`stroke-dasharray="125.6,125.6"`, где длина черты -`125.6` пробел равен `125.6` в сумме это будет вся длина окружности - `251.2`

```html
<svg width="50%" height="50%" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="#FDB900"/>
  <path fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="5" stroke="#fff"
        stroke-dasharray="125.6,125.6"
        d="M50 10
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80"/>
  <text x="50" y="50" text-anchor="middle" dy="7" font-size="20">50%</text>
</svg>
```

### Анимация прогресс бара

**С помощью SMIL**

Для анимации нам нужно увеличивать длину черты от нуля до максимума `251.2`
 соответственно пробел будет уменьшаться от максимума `251.2` до `0`

```
<animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" from ="0, 251.2" to = "251, 0" dur="4s" 
repeatCount="indefinite" />
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="25%" height="25%" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="#FDB900"/>
  <path fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="5" stroke="#fff"
        stroke-dasharray="0,251.2"
        d="M50 10
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80">
     <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" from ="0, 251.2" to = "251, 0" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
   </path>     
  
</svg>
```

**С помощью JS**

Механизм анимации тот же, что и при использовании SMIL - увеличение длины черты от нуля до максимума `251.2`

```
progress.attr({strokeDasharray: '0, 251.2'});
Snap.animate(0,251.2, function( value ) {
    progress.attr({ 'stroke-dasharray':value+',251.2'});
}, 5000);
```

```js
var count = $(('#count'));
$({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: count.text() }, {
  duration: 5000,
  easing: 'linear',
  step: function () {
    count.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter)+ "%");
  }
});

var s = Snap('#animated');
var progress = s.select('#progress');

progress.attr({strokeDasharray: '0, 251.2'});
Snap.animate(0,251.2, function( value ) {
    progress.attr({ 'stroke-dasharray':value+',251.2'});
}, 5000);
```

```css
body{text-align:center;font-family:sans-serif;}
svg{width:30%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.3.0/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<svg id="animated" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="#FDB900"/>
  <path id="progress" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="5" stroke="#fff" fill="none"
        d="M50 10
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80">
  </path>
  <text id="count" x="50" y="50" text-anchor="middle" dy="7" font-size="20">100%</text>
</svg>
```

Пример JS взят из [топика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628297/%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80/628312#628312), на который ссылается автор вопроса