# Как реализовать круглый лоадер?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Помогите с реализацией лоадера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Круговой прогресс бар | SOru](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628297/%d0%9a%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%80/628312#628312)

Answer (score 8):

Алеша, зачем вам круглый лоадер? Выделяйтесь, не будьте как все. Пусть у всех будет круглый, а у вас квадратный:

```js
var num = document.getElementById("num");
var percent = num.innerText;
var interval;
interval = setInterval(function() {
  percent++;
  num.innerHTML = percent + '<span>%</span>';
  if (percent == 100) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 100);
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 140px;
  padding-top: 140px;
  border: 20px solid #dfe8ed;
}

.load__l {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  height: calc(100% + 20px);
  border-top: 20px solid #d74680;
  border-right: 20px solid #d74680;
  opacity: 1;
  animation: 5s linear load__l;
}

.load__r {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  right: -20px;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom: 20px solid #d74680;
  border-left: 20px solid #d74680;
  opacity: 1;
  animation: 10s linear load__r;
}

@keyframes load__l {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  0.1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    width: calc(100% + 20px);
    height: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    width: calc(100% + 20px);
    height: calc(100% + 20px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes load__r {
  0%,
  50% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50.1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    width: calc(100% + 20px);
    height: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    width: calc(100% + 20px);
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

#num {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 140px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: monospace;
}

#num span {
  font-size: 28px;
  padding-left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="load__l"></div>
  <div class="load__r"></div>
  <div id="num"></div>
</div>
```

Или ромбовидный:

```js
var num = document.getElementById("num");
var percent = num.innerText;
var interval;
interval = setInterval(function() {
  percent++;
  num.innerHTML = percent + '<span>%</span>';
  if (percent == 100) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 100);
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 140px;
  padding-top: 140px;
  border: 20px solid #dfe8ed;
  margin: 40px 0 0 40px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.load__l {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  height: calc(100% + 20px);
  border-top: 20px solid #d74680;
  border-right: 20px solid #d74680;
  opacity: 1;
  animation: 5s linear load__l;
}

.load__r {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  right: -20px;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom: 20px solid #d74680;
  border-left: 20px solid #d74680;
  opacity: 1;
  animation: 10s linear load__r;
}

@keyframes load__l {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  0.1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    width: calc(100% + 20px);
    height: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    width: calc(100% + 20px);
    height: calc(100% + 20px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes load__r {
  0%,
  50% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50.1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    width: calc(100% + 20px);
    height: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    width: calc(100% + 20px);
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

#num {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 140px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: monospace;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#num span {
  font-size: 28px;
  padding-left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="load__l"></div>
  <div class="load__r"></div>
  <div id="num"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: У этой анимации есть минус - цифры и keyframes не синхронизированны. Если прокрутить ниже этого(к примеру, тут же, на stackoverflow) блока, то keyframes продолжит работать, а счётчик нет

Comment: просто нужен именно круглый

Comment: ))) нужно было сделать как на картинке. Спасибо Вам за ответ!

Answer (score 4):

Алеша, зачем вам круглый лоадер? Посмотрите, какой интересный вариант я вам предлагаю. Такого точно нет ни у кого, только у вас будет:

```js
var num = document.getElementById("num");
var percent = num.innerText;
var interval;
interval = setInterval(function() {
  percent++;
  num.innerHTML = percent;
  if (percent == 100) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 97);
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 130px;
}

#num {
  position: absolute;
  top: -35px;
  left: 40%;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: monospace;
  transform: rotate(-18deg);
  color: #d74680;
  animation: 9.7s linear percent;
}

.container:before {
  content: "00";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -41px;
  left: 57%;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: monospace;
  letter-spacing: 27px;
  color: #d74680;
  transform: rotate(-70deg);
  zoom: 1;
  animation: 9.7s linear percent;
}

@keyframes percent {
  0% {
    color: #dfe8ed;
    zoom: 1;
  }
  98.999% {
    color: #d74680;
    zoom: 1;
  }
  99% {
    color: #dfe8ed;
    zoom: 1.1;
  }
  99.999% {
    color: #d74680;
    zoom: 1;
  }
  100% {
    color: #d74680;
    zoom: 1;
  }
}

.loader {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 70px;
  background-color: #dfe8ed;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(2px 40px, 20% 0, 40% 40px, 60% 0, 80% 40px, calc(100% - 8px) 0, 100% 16px, 80% 60px, 60% 20px, 40% 60px, 20% 20px, 10px 57px);
  clip-path: polygon(2px 40px, 20% 0, 40% 40px, 60% 0, 80% 40px, calc(100% - 8px) 0, 100% 16px, 80% 60px, 60% 20px, 40% 60px, 20% 20px, 10px 57px);
}

.load {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #d74680;
  animation: 10s linear load;
}

@keyframes load {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.load:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -50px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #d74680;
  animation: 10s linear load__after;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

@keyframes load__after {
  0% {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  }
  14.5% {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  }
  15.5% {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 50% 100%, 0 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 50% 100%, 0 100%);
  }
  34.5% {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 50% 100%, 0 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 50% 100%, 0 100%);
  }
  35.5% {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  }
  54.5% {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  }
  55.5% {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 50% 100%, 0 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 50% 100%, 0 100%);
  }
  74.5% {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 50% 100%, 0 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 50% 100%, 0 100%);
  }
  75.5% {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="loader">
    <div class="load"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="num"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Круглый, как вы просили:

```js
const numb = document.getElementById('count')
let counter = 0
setInterval(() => {
    if (counter === 100) {
        clearInterval()
    } else {
        counter += 1
        numb.textContent = counter + '%'
    }
}, 50)
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
    <path fill="none"
          stroke-linecap="round"
          stroke-width="5"
          stroke="#dfe8ed"
          stroke-dasharray="251.2,0"
          d="M50 10 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80"
    />
    <path fill="none"
          stroke-linecap="round"
          stroke-width="5"
          stroke="#d74680"
          stroke-dasharray="251.2,0"
          d="M50 10 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80"
    >
        <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" from="0,251.2" to="251.2,0" dur="5s"/>
    </path>
    <text id="count" x="50" y="50" text-anchor="middle" dy="7" font-size="20" font-family="arial">
        100%
    </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: самый лучший вариант по читаемости